# batch file which looks for specific files

Tags: batch-file

I'm wondering if a batch file could help to move all the files which i need from a couple of folders to a specific one. The folder structure looks like this example below:

```
d:\home\\(random)\upload\\*.*



d:\home\\(random)\uplaod\\*.*
```

The files in the directory upload should be moved to a specific folder. It can be done by putting every single path in to the batch file, (there are more then 100 folders and there will some more in the future). I guess there is an easier way to get this done.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: below `(random)` - may there be other folders than `upload` and `uplaod`?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /d %%a in ("D:\home\*") do echo move "%%a\upload\*" "x:\destination\
```

This is the syntax for use in a batchfile. For use on commandline replace every `%%a` with `%a`.

The `for /d` returns subfolders of `D:\home\`. Just append the `upload\*` part.

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for. thx. is it possible to check if the files in the folders are older than x minutes

Comment: I mean, to only move files which are older than x minutes?